# Rspec suddenly only running one test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Trying to run rspec (bin/rspec) from my project root, and suddenly it is not running the full test suite - this is usually over 1,000 examples.

```
Finished in 1.88 seconds (files took 5.17 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

I can run individual files or sub-directories (e.g. spec/system/*), and it works fine in other projects run as normal.

The only thing I can think of is that I did enter the test console (bin/rails c test) recently where I made a user, then went onto the test server in localhost, afterwards destroying the user when I realised it wasn't what I needed. I've also reset the test database and cleared my tmp cache just in case.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the cause would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you added `focus: true` to any specs and forgotten about it?

Comment: Thanks @TomDunning - turns out a spec had been committed with 'fit' at the start instead of 'it' which was causing the focus and hadn't been noticed :-) Now fixed and all working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem now fixed - solution:**

I tried running each folder, and I did notice a difference in the focus: true:

bin/rspec spec/controllers:

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}
All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}
```

bin/rspec:

```
Run options: include {:focus=>true}
```

Commented out the lines in spec_helper to check, and it ran everything correctly then:

```
  # config.filter_run_including focus: true
  # config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
```

Searching for focus showed nothing in specs, so I added something to print the metadata in my spec_helper

```
config.before do |x|
  p x.metadata
end
```

and found the one example it was focusing on, and lo and behold the example it happened to have accidentally been pre-pended with 'fit' instead of 'it' from a prior pulled commit which was causing the focus. 
Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed file names? To run rspec by default your filenames should end with `_spec.rb`

Comment: No file names changed unfortunately